# Git Commit works with Xcode beta but not with normal version

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control

I had/have Source Control working with Xcode 7.0 beta 5, but when I try to do a Commit in my newly installed Xcode 7.0 GM it won't work. (The new Xcode 7.0 GM had replaced my previous Xcode 6.4 version, which never had Source Control working.) I get the error message `The working copy "APP NAME" failed to commit files` as is seen in the following image:

[image]

This question is similar to

- [XCode Won't Commit To GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204686/xcode-wont-commit-to-git)
- [Xcode and Git Source Control : “The working copy XXXXX failed to commit files”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694662/xcode-and-git-source-control-the-working-copy-xxxxx-failed-to-commit-files)

but for mine it does work in the beta Xcode version, just not in the standard version.

I tried running the suggested command line commands as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15674397/3681880), but there was no noticeable difference. It seems like there must be some file I could edit or replace, but I don't know where it is. Both of my Xcode versions use the same project folder.

**Update**

Typing `git config --list` inside the project directory I get the following (email changed, but correct):

```
user.email=my_correct_email@mymail.com
user.name=Suragch
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.MongolAppDevelopment-iOS.url=https://github.com/suragch/MongolAppDevelopment-iOS.git
remote.MongolAppDevelopment-iOS.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/MongolAppDevelopment-iOS/*
branch.master.remote=MongolAppDevelopment-iOS
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Again, I can make edits to the project in the standard Xcode but in order to update git I have to go back to the Xcode beta.

Comment: When you "`cd`" to the project directory and type in "`git config --list`", what do you see?  Also, do you even have a "`.git`" directory at the root of your source code folder?  Type in "`ls -a`" in your source code directory to find out.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, There is a `.git` file. See update for config list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git config --list` gives you local and global (and system) git configs.

Check if user.name is still registered in the local repo: `git config --local -l`

If not, it is likely that the XCode7 beta consider a different $HOME, while your command line uses the regular HOME (in which you have a .gitconfig iwth your user.name and user.email)

Simply try and set those in your repo:

```
cd /path/to/rpeo
git config user.name Suragch
git config user.email my_correct_email@mymail.com
```

Comment: You were correct. Typing `git config --local -l` showed that `user.name` and `user.email` were missing from the list. After adding them in the way you said, Source Control worked in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks VonC, that was killing me.

Comment: and, to find the path to the repository for your current directory, you can use `git rev-parse --git-dir`