# Cannot push to gitlab from xcode 7

Tags: gitlab, xcode7

One unhappy side effect of upgrading to Xcode 7 is that I can no longer push to my Gitlab repo.  I have been pushing and pulling from my project without problem for the last two years, so I suspect Xcode 7 is doing something different.  I have verified my u/p for Gitlab by logging into and out of it via the web interface. When I go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts, select the gitlab project, I see that the username and password are in there (just like they have been for 2 years) and I verify that they are correct.

It is worth noting that I can successfully post from Terminal, however, I do not wish to use Terminal to push my code to Gitlab on a regular basis.  Has anyone else encountered this problem since upgrading?  Any suggestions as to a fix?

The specific error I am getting is "Authentication failed because the user name or password was incorrect."  This error appears in the Accounts dialog, as well as after trying to perform a push to the gitlab repo.

Comment: I even had problems using Terminal in this case after upgrade to Xcode7

Comment: Maybe because XCode7 consider a different HOME? As I seen it before in http://stackoverflow.com/a/32795999/6309.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this one was quite a bear to wrestle, and to be honest, I am not sure what the root cause of this error was, but the way I resolved it was this:

1. Removed my old ssh key from GitLab
2. Created a new ssh key on the command line, then added it to GitLab
3. Removed the GitLab repo from Xcode > Preferences > Accounts
4. Re-added the GitLab account, using the SSH Keys Option (which it was before as well, this is not new)
5. Closed Xcode
6. Blew away the working directory of the project
7. Opened Xcode, then chose Source Control > Checkout
8. Provided the SSH address (which you can get from GitLab within your project folder)
9. Made a minor change to the project for the purposes of testing the ability to Push
10. Pushed to GitLab via Xcode Source Control > Push

Voila!  Worked.  This was definitely the nuclear option but it got me working again.  I firmly believe that upgrading Xcode to 7 screwed something up.  If anyone else has this problem I hope this resolves it!

Answer (score 3):

Same issue with xcode 7.

I managed to fix this issue by regenerating the RSA keys and updating them in Gitlab.

<strike>Edit: unfortunately this worked only 1 time</strike>

Edit2: After working one time "right out of the box" after changing the SSH keys, the second time I got the question for login credentials, the dialog where you can choose between username/password and SSH keys. Choosing SSH key then worked. After that the dialog didn't appear anymore.

So, to summarise:

1. XCode push to Gitlab not working (asking for login credentials, SSH key not working)
2. Regenerated SSH RSA key and added it to Gitlab (I removed the old one)
3. Then pushing worked without dialog
4. Next time xcode asked to login by either username/password of SSH keys
5. Selecting SSH keys worked
6. After that the login dialog didn't appear anymore

Comment: Could you post more details?

Comment: Yes, I updated my post as I found this morning that the behaviour was a little more complicated ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I found that Xcode 7 does not like tilt "~" in the URL anymore. Please run "git config --list" and check the URLs. For example, my remote URL looked like this:

```
ssh://nobody@nowhere.com/~/product1.git
```

Xcode can push fine after I run the following commands:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://nobody@nowhere.com/home/nobody/product1.git

git config branch.master.remote ssh://nobody@nowhere.com/home/nobody/product1.git
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that Xcode tried using the wrong key file : .ssh/id_rsa instead of .ssh/id_dsa

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that id_rsa was a symbolic link.

My .ssh/id_rsa file was a symbolic link to another file.  In xcode, I had specified this symbolic link as my ssh private key file.

In this configuration, git pull was working but git push was failing.

Then, in xcode, I changed the ssh private key file to point to a regular file (the file that the symbolic link was pointing to).  And voila, both push and pull are working now.

Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62)