# Can't add Git repository to Xcode 7 using https

Tags: xcode, gitlab

After my upgrade to Xcode 7 the access to my Gitlab repo was denied. I am using HTTPS authentication. When I try to erase and than add a new the repo Xcode gives me an error : Authentication failed because the user name or password was incorrect.

The authentication field is set to Username and Password.

In that question a solution was given but for the SSH authentication:
[Cannot push to gitlab from xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815025/cannot-push-to-gitlab-from-xcode-7)

I prefer to use the HTTP method.

I think this is definitely an issue caused by the upgrade. Has someone else encountered that problem and can You share Your solution.

Comment: I will add that my username and password are accepted in terminal or in source tree application.

Comment: I have the same issue, I can just perform actions via terminal, Xcode does not recognise my credentials. Think it's a problem of the new version

Comment: Hoped that the problem will go away after I upgraded to El Capitan, but it didn't. I will be very grateful if someone can suggest what to do.

Comment: Having same issue.... : (......Anyone got any solution to do it from Xcode 7.

Comment: I am searching for solutions, whenever I think of this issue and have a little time to spare. For now my efforts have been futile. I am using the source tree free application as a substitute. 

I will be sure to post the solution immediately after I find it.

Comment: Same problem here with https repositories! I even created all my repos from scratch. I can do it manually, from the terminal, and started to use SourceTree as an alternative, but Xcode seems to be broken! I can commit locally, but forget about pushing. I keep getting "Unexpected HTTP status code: 404 (-1)" when authenticating.

Comment: I have noticed that this problem is not reproducible when trying to add a Bitbucket repo via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I thought of that issue and tried to add a repository. Since the last time I checked the behaviour I have updated the Xcode to version 7.2. With a great relief I found that the problem has been fixed. However when I tried to commit / push to my repo I encountered an error "Couldn't communicate with a helper application" in Xcode 7". After some digging I found the answer here http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-fix-couldnt-communicate-with-a-helper-application-in-xcode-7/

I just followed the instructions and typed :

xcrun git config --global user.email you@yourdomain.com
xcrun git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"

in the terminal and the problem was fixed.