# Fail to open ssh session. (16) Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, xcode7, openssh, application-loader

how exactly do i fix it I've tried every single link or previous question asked on here so please don't direct me to a link. Can someone please tell me exactly how they fixed it. it would be much appreciated. Thanks 
also i turned my firewall on it had been allows off. but i turned it on to basically tell the fire wall to accept these application (Xcode and application loader). and still the same thing so i should just keep it off i think.

[image]

Comment: In my case I had everything working with XCode 6, including separate SSH keys for GitHub and my GitLab server at work. Update to Xcode 7 and SSH stops working. Still fine everywhere else so I've just opted for jumping over to SourceTree or Terminal. I think it's simply a bug they need to sort out. Based on Google searches it looks like others have been struggling with XCode+SSH throughout the betas.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: You're welcome. I just updated to Xcode 7.1 and it STILL doesn't see my SSH keys properly. Keeps asking me to generate a new, generic key pair. Currently looking into a reference to Xcode not liking the shorthand ~ for referencing HOME. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815025/cannot-push-to-gitlab-from-xcode-7